# Running python on Command prompt:Access is Denied

Tags: python, command-prompt, access-denied

I installed python long back and worked fine for all these months, I could install libraries from command prompt..run python programs using shell from vba until one day..It started failing, I am able to run python scripts from idle but not from command prompt or vba. I have tried checking my permission but to no success.

If I type python on command prompt, it says the app can't run on this pc and later "Access Denied" displays on the prompt.
[image: Image of Error]

Comment: Can you post the specific error message?

Comment: Check if you've executable rights to your `python.exe`. Check the Security Tab in file properties window. And most importantly check the proper python.exe if you've one or more versions in the system

Answer (score 6):

To someone who might find this: I had the same problem, when I checked the python.exe file located at C:\Users{your user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 it had 0 bytes, I just reinstalled it to solve the problem, I don't know how this happened.

Comment: Thanks! Launching python3.exe from the explorer or shortcut worked, I never even looked to see python.exe was 0 bytes! Copying python3.exe to python.exe fixed the issue.